# getting edge with red color

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have the following image:

[image]

The task is to get red border of wood:

[image]

I had tried the following:

Intensity based segmentation

```
img = im2double(imread('img.jpg'));
IDG1 = rgb2gray(img); % conver to gray scale

t = 100; % set a thresholding value

IT = im2bw(IDG1, t/255); % apply the threshold

I2 = ~IT; % get a negative image


I3 = bwareaopen(I2,70); % get rid of small unwanted pixels 

figure, imshow(I3);
```

[image]

Canny/Prewitt edge but not good results. How can I get rid of noise and get clear edge?

```
edgeim = edge(I3,'Prewitt');
figure, imshow(edgeim); % truesize(1)
```

[image]

Comment: Your image is too big. Shrink by like a factor of 10 first with `img_new = imresize(rgb2gray(img), 0.1);` then run edge detection on it: `edgeim = edge(img_new, 'Prewitt');`. You'll probably like those results much better.

Comment: what do you mean by 'red border'?

Comment: If it's a red line, look for red pixels, not for dark pixels. By using `rgb2gray` you throw away the most relevant information! However, looking at the image, the red part is not very red, it looks like JPEG compression is being used? Do you have the option of taking images without lossy JPEG compression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a median filter (r=7) followed by a Sobel filter. This will get you following image:
[image]
If you use binarization on this image, you will get:
[image]

To achieve that in MatLab, you can use following functions:

```
medfilt2(A,[m n]) with m and n = 7
edge(I)
im2bw(I,level) with level = 155
```

For more information you can look at following sources: [I](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/medfilt2.html), [II](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html) and [III](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html)

Comment: I do not use MatLab, but the added functions should achieve the result.